# Url ics import on click

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to make an add to calendar link/button. I, at least, want people to be able to click on a link whereafter the get send to Google calendar where (after login) they should get a popup with do you want to add this calendar to you Google calendar. 
The calendar is a ical file generated by a webpage. So it should be added as an url so Google can update the calendar.

I know it is possible to share a link that looks like: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?cid=xxxxxxxxxx%40import.calendar.google.com after importing the ical url manually. But the problem is that the ical file is generated personally, therefore that wouldn't work.
I also looked around at https://www.addevent.com but could not find a way to make that work. 
Furthermore, I know it is possible somehow because the timetable site of my University has such a button. But I can't figure out how that works.

If possible I, of course, would prefer a button where user can chose between what calendar service (outlook, google, etc) they want to add the ical url.

Comment: Did you go through the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) docs? There's a method called 
[Events.import](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import) that might be related to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What happens when a user clicks on an ics link is determined by their device and application and the settings they have made on that.   All you should do is provide the link to the ics file.

Comment: I could not find anything in the Calendar API docs. I can just provide the users with a link and let them add it manually but that's not what I want.

Comment: @ManteSietsma you found any solution for this?

Comment: No unfortunately not. So I just wrote a little manual.